# php curl header pass authentication

Tags: php, curl, salesforce

I am trying to pass a session id to sales force for an adobe plugin. I am new to curls so not sure if this is correct:

```
$sf_sig = 'https://na25.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/echosign_dev1/template/load/a1t31000002HmjV&email=' . $email;

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        $ch2 = curl_init();

        //ch2 
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $sf_sig);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));
```

Would this be correct when adobe stated I need to use that URL with a session ID? Was confessed on how to set up the header.

Comment: Usually it means a session ID in the query string itself.  If that's $access_token, you need to know how the receiving script expects it, but it would be something like     `code` $sf_sig = "https://na25.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/echosign_dev1/template/load/a1t31000002HmjV&email=' . $email ."&token = ". $access_token;

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, it is part of this great Salesforce API class: https://github.com/jahumes/salesforce-rest-api-php-wrapper/blob/master/SalesforceAPI.php

```
// Set the Authorization header
$request_headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->access_token
);
```

...

```
curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->createCurlHeaderArray($request_headers));
```

and he has a function like this to create the header strings...

```
/**
 * Makes the header array have the right format for the Salesforce API
 *
 * @param  $headers
 * @return array
 */
private function createCurlHeaderArray($headers) {

    $curl_headers = array();
    // Create the header array for the request
    foreach($headers as $key => $header) {
        $curl_headers[] = $key . ': ' . $header;
    }
    return $curl_headers;
}
```